# How to Open Fragment From A Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make navigation drawer with viewpager because i want the navigation drawer to be full screen. i have created a fragment as and added to viewpager. from the navigation fragment on button click i want to open another fragment. i added a code to open another fragment but it crashes the app. how can i do it.
My Button Code

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
       Button btnOpenSlideShow = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnOpenSlideShow);
        btnOpenSlideShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               AllFragment allFragment = new AllFragment();
               FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
               manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout,allFragment,allFragment.getTag())
                       .commit();
           }
       });
return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your crash reports

Comment: @sasikumar iam running it on a android phone

Comment: send log android studio for your crash

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

as `FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();`

```
AllFragment allFragment = new AllFragment();

manager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frameLayout, allFragment )
.addToBackStack(null)
.attach(myFragment)
.commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `getFragmentManager` use `getChildFragmentManager`

```
AllFragment allFragment = new AllFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout,allFragment,allFragment.getTag())
                       .commit();
```

Comment: @v-rund-puro-hit it still crashes

Comment: it still crashes

Comment: what error you are getting? please post your error log